# I can't seem to find the problem with my clearInterval code

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, setinterval, clearinterval

So this following code block uses a setInterval and a clearInterval later. But for some reason interval is not cleared, instead the timing gets messy.
`<button id="startstop" onclick="startStop()">START</button>`

```
var isStart = true;
function startStop(){
    var interval;
    if(isStart){
        interval = setInterval(function (){<!-- *code* -->},1000);
        isStart = false;
    }
    else{
        clearInterval(interval);
        isStart = true;
    }
```

The variable *isStart* is for start-stop toggle in the button, not of significance. I can't find the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You are not stopping interval with another invokation of `startStop`
you are just creating another `interval` variable and not changing previous so every time you click and `isStart` is true you are creating another `setInterval`

Move `var interval;` outside of function body

```js
var isStart = true;
var interval;
function startStop(){
    if(isStart){
        interval = setInterval(function (){console.log('asd')},1000);
        isStart = false;
    }
    else{
        clearInterval(interval);
        isStart = true;
    }
}
startStop();
```

```html
<button onclick="startStop()">startStop</button>
```